# Trigger on delete where customers have had an order

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am creating a previous customers table for customers who are deleted.
I'm wanting to create a trigger after data has been deleted from a customer table.
However i don't want all the customers to be placed in this table only those who have previously placed an order in the system.
I have two tables

```
Customer                 placed_order
Customer_Id              order_id
first_name               order_date
last_name                employee_ID
address                  fk1_customer_id
```

How would it be possible to only insert customers who have a record in the placed orders table?

Comment: And what do you want to do with the records in the `placed_order` table? Should they be deleted or set to null?

Comment: hmm good point, these would also be deleted from the database.

Comment: I've got a procedure that runs that currently deletes from both tables that im using.

Comment: You really don't need a procedure to do this. Just a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` should do the job.

Comment: Hi yeah i know but i've already got a procedure running so may as well use it, have you any idea on the trigger?

Comment: Since the movement of this data to another table is part of the application's functionality, why do you not code your application to do it instead of the deletion/trigger approach? By moving this to another layer you are hiding the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CUSTOMER_AD
  AFTER DELETE ON CUSTOMER
  REFERENCING OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  nPlaced_order_count  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO nPlaced_order_count
    FROM PLACED_ORDERS p
    WHERE p.FK1_CUSTOMER_ID = :OLD.CUSTOMER_ID;

  IF nPlaced_order_count > 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO PREVIOUS_CUSTOMER(whatever, whatever, whatever)
      VALUES(whatever, whatever, whatever);
  END IF;

  -- Now clean up the PLACED_ORDERS table

  DELETE FROM PLACED_ORDERS p
    WHERE p.FK1_CUSTOMER_ID = :OLD.CUSTOMER_ID;
END CUSTOMER_AD;
```

Replace `whatever` with column names and values appropriate for your `PREVIOUS_CUSTOMER` table.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: That seems perfect, just one question what does referencing old as old mean?

Comment: @RichardClare - it means "use the name OLD when referring to values as they were before the DELETE was executed".  I could have said something like `REFERENCING OLD AS O` and then used, e.g. `:O.CUSTOMER_ID` (and thanks for the correction/adding the colon, @AlexPoole).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will have to specify the constraint on `placed_order`.`fk1.customer_id` column to be cascaded on delete. Just alter the foreign key constraint on that column.

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE placed_order
MODIFY CONSTRAINT fk1_fk_customer_id
FOREIGN KEY (fk1_customer_id) REFERENCES customer(customer_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Next, you will need a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger on customer that would keep an audit of those customers who have an entry in the `placed_order` table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_customer_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
REFERENCING new AS new old AS old
AS
  cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO cnt
      FROM placed_order
     WHERE fk_customer_id = :old.customer_id

    IF cnt > 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO previous_customer
        (customer_id, first_name, last_name, address)
        VALUES
        (:old.customer_id, :old.first_name, :old.last_name, :old.address);
    END IF;
END;
/
```