# Why is this PL/SQL trigger not working trying to insert a row in the table customer_log?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, dml

Trying to create a trigger that starts after insert, update or delete on the customer table. The trigger should insert a row in the table customer_log.

I get an error:

> Error(16,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored.

This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADFER_Trigger
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON Customer

DECLARE
    v_event   Customer.EVENT%TYPE;
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING
    THEN
        v_event := 'insert';
    ELSIF UPDATING
    THEN
        v_event := 'Update';
    ELSIF DELETING
    THEN
        v_event := 'Delete';
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO Customer_log (WHO, WHEN, EVENT)
         VALUES (USER, date, v_event);
END;
```

Comment: Maybe the probem is the column Name `WHEN`. It is a keyword! https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm

Comment: If you cant change column name then use double quotes for WHEN.

Comment: While "WHEN"  may be acceptable as a column name, it's not recommended to use. But, the problem is with the "date" in the `values()` .  I presume you wanted to use `SYSDATE`.

Comment: I think, you don't see a full message about compilation error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509335/pl-sql-sql-statement-ignored) you can find something about this.

Comment: Now its working.  It was not enough to change  WHEN to WHAT_DATE. After I changed DATE to SYSDATE I got many errors because the declaration of EVENT. Then  I changed the declaration of EVENT to "EVENT Number" and it work. Thank you Jens, Gagan and Kaushik!